# jquery do stuff to html inside a var

Tags: jquery

```
var d = a piece of html, got it from the server;
//I want to do this to the html from "d"
$('#ls li .ae-lookup-mbtn').prepend("<a href='#' title='+' class='ui-icon <%=ai%>'>+</a>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var d = '<!-- your HTML string -->';

var $d = $(d);  // create a new jQuery object, passing it the HTML string

// perform a find() on the resulting jQuery object, and do your prepend
$d.find('#ls li .ae-lookup-mbtn').prepend("<a href='#' title='+' class='ui-icon <%=ai%>'>+</a>");
```

This doesn't actually change the original string, but it demonstrates how you can send the string to jQuery, and it will convert them to DOM elements that can be manipulated from the resulting jQuery object as though they were added to the DOM.

Note that if you need to find elements at the top level of the string, you'd [use `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead [of `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

If you need the result back into the string, you could add this:

```
d = $('<div>').append( $d ).html();
```

Though it may be that there were some browser corrections done, so there could be changes to the string in addition to the `.prepend()`.